# How to find ids for products that are not on sale but exist in the product details collection using aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am joining a products collection on a productDetail collection where the product _id is the _id in the productDetail collection. I want to be able to find the products which are not on sale but exist in the productDetail table to include in my output as inProductDetailCollection for my reporting. I took a stab at it but it does not work. It always return true even when some _ids are not in the productDetail table. Here is my attempt. How can I get it to set the flag inProductDetailCollection to be false if missing or true if present

```js
     db.getCollection("products").aggregate([
      {
        "$match": {
          "onSale": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "productDetail",
          "localField": "_id",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "productDetail"
        }
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "$expr": {
            "$eq": [
              "$productDetail",
              []
            ]
          }
        }
      },
     
      {
        "$unwind": {
          "path": "$productDetail",
          "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
      },
      {
  
        "$addFields": {
          "onSale": false
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "productId": "$_id",
            "onSale": "$onSale"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "productId": "$_id.productId",
          "onSale": "$_id.onSale",
          "inProductDetailCollection":
           {
                 $cond: { if: { $gt: [ "_id", 0 ] }, then: true, else: false }
          },  
          "_id": 0
        }
      }
    ]
  )
```

Here is a sample of the data. One thing to note is products in the productDetail may not have _ids present in the productDetail table since this table gets uploaded by a nightly batch job. Also, products which are not on sale will have no 'onSale': 'Y' attribute. This is what the data looks like:

```js
    //products collection, some fields omitted for brevity

    [
      {
       "_id": 123345,
       "name": "NutraFast",
       "description": "Supplement",
       "price": 35.99
     },
     { 
       "_id": 13443,
       "name": "BerryBlast",
       "description": "Athletes Sports Drink",
       "price": 12.99
      },
      {
       "_id": 15644
       "name": "MagnoPower-11",
       "description": "Supplement",
       "price": 45.99
      }
     ,{
       "_id": 17011
       "name": "Zinc566",
       "description": "Supplement",
       "price": 25.99
     },
     {
       "_id": 15011
       "name": "VitaMax",
       "description": "Supplement",
       "price": 15.99
      },
      {
       "_id": 15311
        "name": "VitaMax",
         "description": "Supplement",
         "price": 15.99
       },
      { 
        "_id": 15316
        "name": "Chlorphyl Cleanse",
        "description": "Supplement",
        "price": 55.99
      }
     ]
```

Here is the productDetail collection sample

```json
      //productDetail collection
      [
        {
         "_id": 123345,
         "discount": 0.3,
         "amount-per-unit": 50,
         "inStock": "Y"
       },
      {
        "_id": 13443,
        "discount": 0.5,
        "onSale": "Y",
        "amount-per-unit": 60,
        "inStock": "Y"
        "onSale":"Y"
      },
      {
        "_id" : 15644,
        "discount": 0.5,
        "onSale": "Y",
        "amount-per-unit": 60,
        "inStock": "Y"
      },

      {
        "_id" : 15011,
        "discount": 0.5,
        "amount-per-unit": 60,
        "inStock": "Y"
      },

      {
        "_id" : 17011,
        "discount": 0.5,
        "amount-per-unit": 60,
        "inStock": "Y"
      } 

    ]
```

Comment: A sample document from `products` and `productDetail` collections would help a lot. Could you post them please?

Comment: Without having sample data for both those collections, we can only _guess_ what the query should be. Also add what the expected result of your query should be for those sample documents, after you add that to your question. I assume `product` & `productDetail` are 1-to-1 since you're using the same `_id` for both.

Comment: I have added created a subset of the fields as it is a huge number of fields. Thank you

Comment: is ur dataset correct https://mongoplayground.net/p/BGF7oXU87Y-
for example there are duplicate onSale and also duplicate _id in product

Comment: I corrected the last _id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very difficult to understand what you actually need. However, I have taken the liberty of correcting some invalid object structure in your sample documents and below are two possible aggregations that should hopefully get you the output you're looking for:

**Example 1**

This will return ***only*** the `products` documents that have:

- a matching `productDetail`
- with a field named `productDetail` that includes the `$lookup` document
- with a field named `inProductDetailCollectionButNotOnSale`
- which will be `true` ***only*** if the `product` is ***not*** on sale
- or `false` otherwise

```js
db.getCollection("products").aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "productDetail",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "productDetail"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$productDetail"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      inProductDetailCollectionButNotOnSale: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$productDetail.onSale",
              "Y"
            ]
          },
          false,
          true
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wlZEcx5tXOU) for a working example.**

---

**Example 2**

This will return ***all*** `products` documents and includes:

- a field named `productDetail` that includes the `$lookup` document (if any)
- with a field named `inProductDetailCollectionButNotOnSale`
- which will be `true` ***only*** if the `product` has a matching `productDetail` ***and*** is ***not*** on sale
- or `false` otherwise

```js
db.getCollection("products").aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "productDetail",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "productDetail"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$productDetail",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      inProductDetailCollectionButNotOnSale: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: [
                  "$productDetail",
                  0
                ]
              },
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$productDetail.onSale",
                  "Y"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          true,
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L1dfs01HZy8) for a working example.**

**Note**: for clarity and in case anyone else wonders why this part works:

```js
$gt: [
   "$productDetail",
   0
]
```

Mongodb has a [Comparison/Sort Order](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#comparison-sort-order) which lists the BSON types in order from lowest to highest. What I have done is compare the `$productDetail` field against a `Number`. Since `Object` is 4th on the list and `Number` is 3rd on the list it basically means if `$productDetail` exists in the document then it will be on level 4 which is higher (`$gt`) than a the number zero which is on level 3 on the list.

It returns true because it essentially translates to:

```js
$gt: [
   4, // 4 is greater than 3
   3
]
```

If `$productDetail` doesn't exist then it will return false because a `null` is on level 2 and `Number` is higher on level 3 so it translates to:

```js
$gt: [
   2, // 2 is NOT greater than 3
   3
]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this portion means in the $and?                 $gt: [
                  "$productDetail",
                  0
                ]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution.  I've tried various solutions but they just did not work, so I'm very appreciative of this solution

Comment: @BreenDeen because productDetail is an added array field that was then unwound, that condition basically checks for it's existence. Because some documents won't have it ( the ones without a matching productDetail document) we need them to be false. If productDetail exists then that part of the $and will be true.

Comment: @BreenDeen I've added an explanation on why that part works.